# CoreUi Side bar menu link highlight not working

Tags: angular, core-ui

I am using

```
"@coreui/angular": "^2.2.0",
    "@coreui/coreui-pro": "^2.1.3",
```

and in side menu the currently selected menu item is not highlighted.
When I debug that I found the active class is getting removed.

If I adds active class using code it automatically removes the active class.

[image]

[image]

This is my github issue link

https://github.com/coreui/coreui-angular/issues/66

Is anyone have idea for the above issue